# MAMP 2 - Apache. Cannot use folders on desktop

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp

I updated my MAMP to version 2 and ran into a couple of problems. I've always had my projects in a folder `/Desktop/Projects` and pointed my localhost there. No problem whatsoever, I could see my filelistings etc.

However, after updating, I now get a '403 Forbidden' error, stating that I do not have permission to access '/' on this server.

I'm not sure what I did before to make this work, and I suspect this has something to do with Apache's and/or MAMP's settings? Could someone perhaps give me some pointers? Thanks.

PS: Not sure if this is the right Stackexchange site, but Webmasters didn't have a MAMP tag, so I figured I'd post it here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you didn't set the Disk Location correctly...
In MAMP, click the HOSTS tab, there you'll see Disk Location.
You can choose the directory here, and click Permissions to make sure things are set correctly.
The path to your web-root should be something like `/Users/cabaret/Desktop/Projects`

Comment: When I try to set the root, it won't let me select any folder on my Desktop, nor the Desktop itself. I don't understand why it blocks that? Not like I'm going to allow people access to my desktop..

Comment: Messing around in the Permissions tab fixed it, although I'm not sure what I did exactly. I just checked everything ;D Thanks a lot!